# Bluetooth issue

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am building an app which connects through bluetooth but the problem is that it is crushing the device when I try to open the activity as the app should transfer the data from arduino to android app and display on it.I am having problem with the default bluetooth device issue when i see it on terminal

Here is the code

```
public class BlankActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnOn, btnOff;
    TextView  txtString, txtStringLength, sensorView0;
    Handler bluetoothIn;

    final int handlerState = 0;                         //used to identify handler message
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();

    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

    // SPP UUID service - this should work for most devices
    private static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    // String for MAC address
    private static String address;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.sensors_layout);


        //Link the buttons and textViews to respective views
        btnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOn);
        btnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOff);
        txtString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtString);
        txtStringLength = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testView1);
        sensorView0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView0);


        bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == handlerState) {                                        //if message is what we want
                    String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;                                                                // msg.arg1 = bytes from connect thread
                    recDataString.append(readMessage);                                    //keep appending to string until ~
                    int endOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("~");                    // determine the end-of-line
                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // make sure there data before ~
                        String dataInPrint = recDataString.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);    // extract string
                        //txtString.setText("Data Received = " + dataInPrint);
                        int dataLength = dataInPrint.length();                            //get length of data received
                        //txtStringLength.setText("String Length = " + String.valueOf(dataLength));

                        if (recDataString.charAt(0) == '#')                                //if it starts with # we know it is what we are looking for
                        {

                            String sensor0 = recDataString.substring(1, endOfLineIndex);             //get sensor value from string between indices 1-5
                            //String sensor1 = recDataString.substring(6, 10);            //same again...
                            //String sensor2 = recDataString.substring(11, 15);
                            //String sensor3 = recDataString.substring(16, 20);

                            sensorView0.setText(" Intensity = " + sensor0 + " Raw ");    //update the textviews with sensor values
                            //sensorView1.setText(" Sensor 1 Voltage = " + sensor1 + "V");
                            //sensorView2.setText(" Sensor 2 Voltage = " + sensor2 + "V");
                            //sensorView3.setText(" Sensor 3 Voltage = " + sensor3 + "V");
                        }
                        recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());                    //clear all string data
                        // strIncom =" ";
                        dataInPrint = " ";
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();       // get Bluetooth adapter
        checkBTState();


        // Set up onClick listeners for buttons to send 1 or 0 to turn on/off LED
        btnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mConnectedThread.write("0");    // Send "0" via Bluetooth
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Measurement Off!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        btnOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mConnectedThread.write("1");    // Send "1" via Bluetooth
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please Wait ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {

        return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
        //creates secure outgoing connecetion with BT device using UUID
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //Get MAC address from DeviceListActivity via intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        //Get the MAC address from the DeviceListActivty via EXTRA
        address = intent.getStringExtra(MainLayout.EXTRA_ADDRESS);

        //create device and set the MAC address //I am having problem here in android monitor 
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        try {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // Establish the Bluetooth socket connection.
        try {
            btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                //insert code to deal with this
            }
        }
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        //I send a character when resuming.beginning transmission to check device is connected
        //If it is not an exception will be thrown in the write method and finish() will be called
```

// I have problem with this line
           ****mConnectedThread.write("x");**
        }**

```
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            //Don't leave Bluetooth sockets open when leaving activity
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            //insert code to deal with this
        }
    }

    //Checks that the Android device Bluetooth is available and prompts to be turned on if off
    private void checkBTState() {

        if (btAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Device does not support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            } else {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    //create new class for connect thread
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        //creation of the connect thread
        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try {
                //Create I/O streams for connection
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }


        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytes;

            // Keep looping to listen for received messages
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);            //read bytes from input buffer
                    String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler
                    bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //write method
        public void write(String input) {
            byte[] msgBuffer = input.getBytes();           //converts entered String into bytes
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);                //write bytes over BT connection via outstream
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //if you cannot write, close the application
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();

            }
        }
    }


}
```

This is the crash code when I am facing when I click the button

```
     at de.zmt.photometerapp.BlankActivity$3.onClick(BlankActivity.java:114)
```

Comment: what is the specific error you are seeing

Comment: You should paste the crash log..... not only the code.